# Panels and pager in the pane

Tags: 7, panels, paging

Is it possible to load next page of the view inside a pane (by using pager)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found out what was missing. I had to turn on Ajax, in the View.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to set the *Use panel path* to *Yes* in order for things like pagers, exposed filters/exposed sorting, and ajax to work properly.[image]